# How align two TextViews in one line on left side

Tags: android, layout, textview

I should align two TextViews in one lane. But the first TextView should be cropped when it's too a long.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    tools:text="subtitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    tools:text=" * date" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

I have issue. When the first TextView has too long text, so the second TextView is hidden.

[First case. Short subtitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znK24.png)

[Second case. Long subtitle. Second TextView is cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkXUA.png)

Both views should be placed on the left side when text short. But the first text should be cropped when text is long.

Comment: I can't use weight, because this view is used in RecyclerView and performance can decrease.

Comment: Weight don't good decision as well, because view can has long width, but TextViews have different width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve both, you need **wrap_content** in the Layout **wrap_content in the second TextView** and the **combination of width:0dp and layout_weight:1 in the first TextView**. This way the second TextView will always be large enough to display the content and the first TextView will extend up to the available space next to it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="this text is tool long so it will be cut. this text is tool long so it will be cut." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=" * date" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is the best solution in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Layout with `weight`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="subtitlevvnvnvnnvnvnvnvnvnvnvnvnvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text=" * date"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this does not align the two textviews on the left when the text in the left textview is short

Comment: @BjörnKechel, you must have to provide a specific width to work with `ellipsize`, making it `wrap_content` will match the parent.

Answer (score 1):

> Try replacing the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and add `layout_weight=1` for both the TextViews

**Change To:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        style="@style/m4w_TextView.Subtitle"
        fontPath="fonts/InterstatePro-Light.otf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="subtitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        style="@style/m4w_TextView.Subtitle"
        fontPath="fonts/InterstatePro-Light.otf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text=" * date" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding in both the TextView

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                tools:text="subtitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                tools:text=" * date" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this It may help in equal size . I have given them the layout weight , you can change it and adjust textviews accordingly . you can read more about linear layout weight from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            style="@style/m4w_TextView.Subtitle"
            fontPath="fonts/InterstatePro-Light.otf"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:text="subtitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            style="@style/m4w_TextView.Subtitle"
            fontPath="fonts/InterstatePro-Light.otf"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text=" * date" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. You just need to place date element first, then the subtitle in relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                tools:text=" * date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
                tools:text="subtitle" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may help you

```
  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:text="ajay bhimani this is practice"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:text=" * date"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight = 1
                tools:text="subtitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight = 1
                tools:text=" * date" />
        </LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        tools:text="subtitle  df  ds fgfg cvb vbcfvnb cbxfcb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text=" * date" />
</LinearLayout>
```